# How to install an extension for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vim

I am trying to install a [Vim extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) for Visual Studio 2008.

So I downloaded a file called `VsVim.vsix`. And I googled how to install it, seems the answer is to use Visual Studio Extension Manager which comes with VS 2010.

Can anyone give me some hint how to install this on VS 2008, please?

Comment: can anyone answer this question please? i also encountered same issue..but i have different extension to be installed: 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VsVim cannot be installed for Visual Studio 2008.